# How to prevent the user from clicking an UI element in multiple browser tabs in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web, frontend

I have an image on my website(eg - [www.somewebsite.com](http://www.somewebsite.com)) on click of which I open an iframe(different origin). I want to restrict the user from clicking the image when my site is opened by user in multiple tabs. When the user opens my website in multiple tabs in browser on every tab except the first one should show an hover text like you have another session enabled on different tab and aslo I am hiding the image once user clicks it and iframe is loaded.
I am wondering how to do that whether to use cookies or localStorage or broadcastApi, I also need to support all major browsers
Any help would be really appreciated.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { ProfilePage } from "./components/ProfilePage";
import { ProfileDetailPage } from "./components/ProfileDetailPage";
import { FeedPage } from "./components/FeedPage";
import { HomePage } from "./components/HomePage";
import ChatBot from "./ChatBot";


function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">To Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/profile">To Profile</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/profile/andrew" exact>To Andrew's Profile</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/feed">To Feed</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ChatBot />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
          <Route exact path="/profile" component={ProfilePage} />
          <Route path="/profile/:username" component={ProfileDetailPage} />
          <Route path="/feed" component={FeedPage} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

import { useState } from 'react';
import React from 'react';

export default function ChatBot() {
  const [showIcon, setShowIcon] = useState(true);
  const addChatScript = () => {
    setShowIcon(false);
    var srcUrl = 'https://otherwebsite.com/chat.js';
    var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
    scriptTag.id = 'chatbot';
    scriptTag.setAttribute('src', srcUrl);
    scriptTag.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);
  };
  return (
    <div
      className="bot"
      style={{
        position: 'fixed',
        right: '20px',
        bottom: '20px',
        cursor: 'pointer',
      }}
    >
      {showIcon &&(
        <img
          src="https://images.ctfassets.net/hrltx12pl8hq/3MbF54EhWUhsXunc5Keueb/60774fbbff86e6bf6776f1e17a8016b4/04-nature_721703848.jpg?fit=fill&w=480&h=270"
          onClick={() => addChatScript()}
          alt=""
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

I have a ChatBot component which is a app level component.
```

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve what you want using SharedWorker
. From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker):

> The SharedWorker interface represents a specific kind of worker that
> can be accessed from several browsing contexts, such as several
> windows, iframes or even workers.

Basically, you may use it to manage which page is the main one.